# Solutions to $a^2=p_n+p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}$

Tags: number-theory

Let be $a$ a positive integer.
Let be $p_n$, $p_{n+1}$, $p_{n+2}$ three consecutive primes.
I am searching all the possible solutions to:

$$a^2=p_n+p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}$$

A possible solution is $a=7$, then $p_n=13$, $p_{n+1}=17$ and $p_{n+2}=19$.

Are plenty of solutions? Are they infinite? Is it an open problem of maths?

Comment: $11^2=37+41+43$ so there is more than the one solution you report.

Comment: @Keith Backman any other solution?

Comment: At least one of the primes has to be one less than a multiple of four.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of solutions. This is the PARI/GP code to find them upto a given limit :

```
? [a,b,c]=primes(3);while(c<10^5,[a,b,c]=[b,c,nextprime(c+1)];if(issquare(vecsum
([a,b,c]))==1,print([a,b,c])))
[13, 17, 19]
[37, 41, 43]
[277, 281, 283]
[313, 317, 331]
[613, 617, 619]
[7591, 7603, 7607]
[8209, 8219, 8221]
[12157, 12161, 12163]
[14557, 14561, 14563]
[15679, 15683, 15727]
[16267, 16273, 16301]
[23053, 23057, 23059]
[32233, 32237, 32251]
[42953, 42961, 42967]
[44887, 44893, 44909]
[55213, 55217, 55219]
[81013, 81017, 81019]
[94687, 94693, 94709]
?
```

Comment: are there solutions in which none of the three consecutive primes is a Pytagorean prime that is of the form $4n+1$?

Comment: Are there solutions in which all the three consecutive primes are Pytagorean primes?